# Preparing a React component to publish on npm

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a component that I want to publish in npm, I tested simply by importing it from the components folder in the project.

I managed to publish it, but now I get:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@*/*/index.js Module
>   parse failed: Unexpected token (11:8) You may need an appropriate
>   loader to handle this file type.

My index.js is as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import Main from "./bootstrap/containers/main"

export default class BootstrapTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Main {...this.props} changePage={(p) => this.props.changePage(p)}/>
    )
  }
}
```

Side note: I shouldn't need to change the webpack config as it should work as it is, like many other packages I am currently using.

Comment: So you need to turn it into commonjs + es/js.

Comment: Thanks! looking at this now: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/04/14/react-npm-how-to-publish-a-react-component-to-npm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it, thanks to @zerkms for the first step needed for my research.

**Steps:**

1. Installed webpack and added the following config to **webpack.config.js** (my index.js is in ./src and externals are very important so you don't load instances of react):

> ```
> var path = require('path');
>
> module.exports = {
>   mode: 'production',
>   entry: './src/index.js',
>   output: {
>     path: path.resolve('dist'),
>     filename: 'index.js',
>     libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
>   },
>   module: {
>     rules: [{
>       test: /\.js?$/,
>       exclude: /(node_modules)/,
>       use: {
>         loader: 'babel-loader'
>       }
>     }]
>   },
>   externals: {
>     'react': 'react',
>     'react-dom': 'react-dom',
>     'react-bootstrap': 'react-bootstrap'
>   }
> }
> ```

2. Created a **.babelrc** in the main folder with the following:

> ```
> {
>     "presets": [
>         "react",
>         "env",
>         "stage-0"
>     ]
> }
> ```

3. Created an **.npmignore** file with:

> ```
> src
> .babelrc
> webpack.config.js
> ```

4. Created a **package.json** file with the following (your packages might be different but basically just install what you need "npm i package-name"):

> ```
> {
>   "name": "@scope/package-name",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "description": "My component",
>   "main": "dist/index.js",
>   "scripts": {
>     "build": "webpack"
>   },
>   "repository": {
>     "type": "git",
>     "url": "git+https://github.com/myrepo.git"
>   },
>   "keywords": [
>     "react",
>     "bootstrap"
>   ],
>   "author": "Me",
>   "license": "MIT",
>   "peerDependencies": {
>     "react": "^16.4.0",
>     "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
>     "react-dom": "^16.4.0"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "react": "^16.4.0",
>     "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
>     "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
>     "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
>     "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
>     "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
>     "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
>     "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
>     "path": "^0.12.7",
>     "webpack": "^4.5.0",
>     "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
>   }
> }
> ```

5. npm install
6. npm run build
7. npm version 1.0.0 (increment for updates)
8. npm publish

done!

These articles were great help:

- [React + npm - How to Publish a React Component to npm](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/04/14/react-npm-how-to-publish-a-react-component-to-npm)
- [How to create a React component and publish it on NPM](https://medium.com/@BrodaNoel/how-to-create-a-react-component-and-publish-it-in-npm-668ad7d363ce)
- [A guide    to building a React component with webpack 4, publishing
  to npm, and    deploying the demo to GitHub Pages](https://medium.com/dailyjs/building-a-react-component-with-webpack-publish-to-npm-deploy-to-github-guide-6927f60b3220)