# react.js npm package can't be resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to create a simple React module. My project structure looks like this :

```
project
|---src
     |---Login.js
     |---login.css
     |---index.js
...
```

I have used `create-react-app` boilerplate.

Now when I have published the repo, it gives me :
**Could not find module in path: 'react-mua-login' relative to '/src/index.js'**

What is the problem actually ?

- Repo : https://github.com/maifeeulasad/react-mua-login
- npm package name : react-mua-login
- codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mua-login-sample-x12dr?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import Login component correctly:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Login from "react-mua-login/src/Login";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Login />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

## [Working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-mua-login-sample-c3lxe?file=/src/index.js)

## EDIT

If you want to use method like `import Login from "react-mua-login"`, you should export `Login` component from your main entry file.

For example, you can create index.js in the project root directory and export Login component like this:

```js
import Login from "./src/Login";
export default Login;
```

Recommended readling list: [Preparing a React component to publish on npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710968/preparing-a-react-component-to-publish-on-npm)

Comment: it works, but can you tell me, why the image is not being rendered ?? is it something related to codesandbox, or I need to put assets in a different way ?

Comment: It says it cannot find file: https://codesandbox.io/api/v1/sandboxes/c3lxe/fs/node_modules/react-mua-login/src/login.svg, I'd recommend to try it in your pc not in sandbox. Make sure svg file is included when you install react-mua-login

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like `react-mua-login` is a library but an application. You cannot import anything from it and it generates a weird error.

You need a [`main`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) property in `react-mua-login`'s `package.json` so you can import things from it.

Also, you should probably move some dependencies in `react-mua-login` from `dependencies` to `peerDependencies` or `devDependencies`.

- `@testing-library/jest-dom` dev
- `@testing-library/react` dev
- `@testing-library/user-event` dev
- `react` dev & peer
- `react-dom` dev & peer
- `react-scripts` dev

It is often best that a lib doesn't ship with its own version of dependencies (especially `react`)